# Understanding how to use CGI programming with C and HTML

Tags: html, c, input, output, cgi

I'm attempting to use a local server made in C with an HTML page run on this server that will be able to interact with a program i made to be able to run bash commands which works perfectly outside of the html page but needs to be able to receive input from the user via text box on the web page, display the command entered as well as the output on the html page. Right now when i click the submit button on the html page it goes to localhost:PORT/pexec.cgi but shows absolutely no display at all, just white space. What am i doing wrong and how can i get this to work so that it will correctly display output?

**WCServer.c**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>       // socket definitions
#include <sys/types.h>        // socket types
#include <arpa/inet.h>        // inet (3) funtions
#include <unistd.h>           // misc. UNIX functions
#include <signal.h>           // signal handling
#include <stdlib.h>           // standard library
#include <stdio.h>            // input/output library
#include <string.h>           // string library
#include <errno.h>            // error number library
#include <fcntl.h>            // for O_* constants
#include <sys/mman.h>         // mmap library
#include <sys/types.h>        // various type definitions
#include <sys/stat.h>         // more constants

// global constants
#define PORT 3838             // port to connect on
#define LISTENQ 10            // number of connections

int list_s;                   // listening socket

// structure to hold the return code and the filepath to serve to client.
typedef struct {
  int returncode;
  char *filename;
} httpRequest;

// Structure to hold variables that will be placed in shared memory
typedef struct {
  pthread_mutex_t mutexlock;
  int totalbytes;
} sharedVariables;

// headers to send to clients
char *header200 = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\nServer: CS241Serv v0.1\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";
char *header400 = "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\nServer: CS241Serv v0.1\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";
char *header404 = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\nServer: CS241Serv v0.1\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n";

// get a message from the socket until a blank line is recieved
char *getMessage(int fd) {

    // A file stream
    FILE *sstream;

    // Try to open the socket to the file stream and handle any failures
    if( (sstream = fdopen(fd, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file descriptor in getMessage()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Size variable for passing to getline
    size_t size = 1;

    char *block;

    // Allocate some memory for block and check it went ok
    if( (block = malloc(sizeof(char) * size)) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory to block in getMessage\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Set block to null    
    *block = '\0';

    // Allocate some memory for tmp and check it went ok
    char *tmp;
    if( (tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * size)) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory to tmp in getMessage\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Set tmp to null
    *tmp = '\0';

    // Int to keep track of what getline returns
    int end;
    // Int to help use resize block
    int oldsize = 1;

    // While getline is still getting data
    while( (end = getline( &tmp, &size, sstream)) > 0)
    {
        // If the line its read is a caridge return and a new line were at the end of the header so break
        if( strcmp(tmp, "\r\n") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Resize block
        block = realloc(block, size+oldsize);
        // Set the value of oldsize to the current size of block
        oldsize += size;
        // Append the latest line we got to block
        strcat(block, tmp);
    }

    // Free tmp a we no longer need it
    free(tmp);

    // Return the header
    return block;

}

// send a message to a socket file descripter
int sendMessage(int fd, char *msg) {
    return write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));
}

// Extracts the filename needed from a GET request and adds public_html to the front of it
char * getFileName(char* msg)
{
    // Variable to store the filename in
    char * file;
    // Allocate some memory for the filename and check it went OK
    if( (file = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(msg))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory to file in getFileName()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Get the filename from the header
    sscanf(msg, "GET %s HTTP/1.1", file);

    // Allocate some memory not in read only space to store "public_html"
    char *base;
    if( (base = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(file) + 18))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory to base in getFileName()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* ph = "public_html";

    // Copy public_html to the non read only memory
    strcpy(base, ph);

    // Append the filename after public_html
    strcat(base, file);

    // Free file as we now have the file name in base
    free(file);

    // Return public_html/filetheywant.html
    return base;
}

// parse a HTTP request and return an object with return code and filename
httpRequest parseRequest(char *msg){
    httpRequest ret;

    // A variable to store the name of the file they want
    char* filename;
    // Allocate some memory to filename and check it goes OK
    if( (filename = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(msg))) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory to filename in parseRequest()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Find out what page they want
    filename = getFileName(msg);

    // Check if its a directory traversal attack
    char *badstring = "..";
    char *test = strstr(filename, badstring);

    // Check if they asked for / and give them input.html
    int test2 = strcmp(filename, "public_html/");

    // Check if the page they want exists 
    FILE *exists = fopen(filename, "r" );

    // If the badstring is found in the filename
    if( test != NULL )
    {
        // Return a 400 header and 400.html
        ret.returncode = 400;
        ret.filename = "400.html";
    }

    // If they asked for / return input.html
    else if(test2 == 0)
    {
        ret.returncode = 200;
        ret.filename = "public_html/input.html";
    }

    // If they asked for a specific page and it exists because we opened it sucessfully return it 
    else if( exists != NULL )
    {

        ret.returncode = 200;
        ret.filename = filename;
        // Close the file stream
        fclose(exists);
    }

    // If we get here the file they want doesn't exist so return a 404
    else
    {
        ret.returncode = 404;
        ret.filename = "404.html";
    }

    // Return the structure containing the details
    return ret;
}

// print a file out to a socket file descriptor
int printFile(int fd, char *filename) {

    /* Open the file filename and echo the contents from it to the file descriptor fd */

    // Attempt to open the file 
    FILE *read;
    if( (read = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file in printFile()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Get the size of this file for printing out later on
    int totalsize;
    struct stat st;
    stat(filename, &st);
    totalsize = st.st_size;

    // Variable for getline to write the size of the line its currently printing to
    size_t size = 1;

    // Get some space to store each line of the file in temporarily 
    char *temp;
    if(  (temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * size)) == NULL )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory to temp in printFile()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // Int to keep track of what getline returns
    int end;

    // While getline is still getting data
    while( (end = getline( &temp, &size, read)) > 0)
    {
        sendMessage(fd, temp);
    }

    // Final new line
    sendMessage(fd, "\n");

    // Free temp as we no longer need it
    free(temp);

    // Return how big the file we sent out was
    return totalsize;

}

// clean up listening socket on ctrl-c
void cleanup(int sig) {

    printf("Cleaning up connections and exiting.\n");

    // try to close the listening socket
    if (close(list_s) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling close()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Close the shared memory we used
    shm_unlink("/sharedmem");

    // exit with success
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int printHeader(int fd, int returncode)
{
    // Print the header based on the return code
    switch (returncode)
    {
        case 200:
        sendMessage(fd, header200);
        return strlen(header200);
        break;

        case 400:
        sendMessage(fd, header400);
        return strlen(header400);
        break;

        case 404:
        sendMessage(fd, header404);
        return strlen(header404);
        break;
    }
}


// Increment the global count of data sent out 
int recordTotalBytes(int bytes_sent, sharedVariables *mempointer)
{
    // Lock the mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(*mempointer).mutexlock);
    // Increment bytes_sent
    (*mempointer).totalbytes += bytes_sent;
    // Unlock the mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*mempointer).mutexlock);
    // Return the new byte count
    return (*mempointer).totalbytes;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int conn_s;                  //  connection socket
    short int port = PORT;       //  port number
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr; //  socket address structure

    // set up signal handler for ctrl-c
    (void) signal(SIGINT, cleanup);

    // create the listening socket
    if ((list_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating listening socket.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // set all bytes in socket address structure to zero, and fill in the relevant data members
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(port);

    // bind to the socket address
    if (bind(list_s, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error calling bind()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    // Listen on socket list_s
    if( (listen(list_s, 10)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Listening\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    // Set up some shared memory to store our shared variables in

    // Close the shared memory we use just to be safe
    shm_unlink("/sharedmem");

    int sharedmem;

    // Open the memory
    if( (sharedmem = shm_open("/sharedmem", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening sharedmem in main() errno is: %s ", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Set the size of the shared memory to the size of my structure
    ftruncate(sharedmem, sizeof(sharedVariables) );

    // Map the shared memory into our address space
    sharedVariables *mempointer;

    // Set mempointer to point at the shared memory
    mempointer = mmap(NULL, sizeof(sharedVariables), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, sharedmem, 0); 

    // Check the memory allocation went OK
    if( mempointer == MAP_FAILED )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting shared memory for sharedVariables in recordTotalBytes() error is %d \n ", errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Initalise the mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&(*mempointer).mutexlock, NULL);
    // Set total bytes sent to 0
    (*mempointer).totalbytes = 0;

    // Size of the address
    int addr_size = sizeof(servaddr);

    // Sizes of data were sending out
    int headersize;
    int pagesize;
    int totaldata;
    // Number of child processes we have spawned
    int children = 0;
    // Variable to store the ID of the process we get when we spawn
    pid_t pid;

    // Loop infinitly serving requests
    while(1)
    {

        // If we haven't already spawned 10 children fork
        if( children <= 10)
        {
            pid = fork();
            children++;
        }

        // If the pid is -1 the fork failed so handle that
        if( pid == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"can't fork, error %d\n" , errno);
            exit (1);
        }

        // Have the child process deal with the connection
        if ( pid == 0)
        { 
            // Have the child loop infinetly dealing with a connection then getting the next one in the queue
            while(1)
            {
                // Accept a connection
                conn_s = accept(list_s, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, &addr_size);

                // If something went wrong with accepting the connection deal with it
                if(conn_s == -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error accepting connection \n");
                    exit (1);
                }

                // Get the message from the file descriptor
                char * header = getMessage(conn_s);

                // Parse the request
                httpRequest details = parseRequest(header);

                // Free header now were done with it
                free(header);

                // Print out the correct header
                headersize = printHeader(conn_s, details.returncode);

                // Print out the file they wanted
                pagesize = printFile(conn_s, details.filename);

                // Increment our count of total datasent by all processes and get back the new total
                totaldata = recordTotalBytes(headersize+pagesize, mempointer);

                // Print out which process handled the request and how much data was sent
                printf("Process %d served a request of %d bytes. Total bytes sent %d  \n", getpid(), headersize+pagesize, totaldata); 

                // Close the connection now were done
                close(conn_s);
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Pexec.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static char* args[512];
pid_t pid;
int command_pipe[2];

#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1

static int command(int input, int first, int last)
{
    int pipettes[2];

    pipe( pipettes );   
    pid = fork();


    if (pid == 0) {
        if (first == 1 && last == 0 && input == 0) {
            // First command
            dup2( pipettes[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO );
        } else if (first == 0 && last == 0 && input != 0) {
            // Middle command
            dup2(input, STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(pipettes[WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        } else {
            // Last command
            dup2( input, STDIN_FILENO );
        }

        if (execvp( args[0], args) == -1)
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    if (input != 0) 
        close(input);


    close(pipettes[WRITE]);


    if (last == 1)
        close(pipettes[READ]);

    return pipettes[READ];
}


static void cleanup(int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        wait(NULL); 
}

static int run(char* cmd, int input, int first, int last);
static char line[1024];
static int n = 0; /* number of calls to 'command' */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while (1) {

      //  for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
       //     strcat(line, argv[i]);
       //     strcat(line, " ");
       // }

        /* Read a command line */
        //if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) 
            //return 0;
        int InputLength = atoi(getenv("INPUT_LENGTH"));
        fread(line, InputLength, 1, stdin);

        int input = 0;
        int first = 1;

        char* cmd = line;
        char* next = strchr(cmd, '@'); /* Find first '|' */

        while (next != NULL) {
            /* 'next' points to '|' */
            *next = '\0';
            input = run(cmd, input, first, 0);

            cmd = next + 1;
            next = strchr(cmd, '@'); /* Find next '|' */
            first = 0;
        }
        input = run(cmd, input, first, 1);
        cleanup(n);
        n = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void split(char* cmd);

static int run(char* cmd, int input, int first, int last)
{
    split(cmd);
    if (args[0] != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) 
            exit(0);
        n += 1;
        return command(input, first, last);
    }
    return 0;
}

static char* skipwhite(char* s)
{
    while (isspace(*s)) ++s;
    return s;
}

static void split(char* cmd)
{
    cmd = skipwhite(cmd);
    char* next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
    int i = 0;

    while(next != NULL) {
        next[0] = '\0';
        args[i] = cmd;
        ++i;
        cmd = skipwhite(next + 1);
        next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
    }

    if (cmd[0] != '\0') {
        args[i] = cmd;
        next = strchr(cmd, '\n');
        next[0] = '\0';
        ++i; 
    }

    args[i] = NULL;
}
```

**input.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h3><center>The Html Page Title  </center></h3>

<div>
  <form method="POST" action="pexec.cgi">
    <label for="cmmd">Command</label>
    <input type="text" id="cmmd" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your Command here and then hit Run! Below">

    <label for="lname">Entered Command </label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="This is what you entered..."> 

    <label for="lname">Standard Output </label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Standard Output will be shown here..."> 

    <label for="lname">Standard Error </label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="standard error will be shown here...">


    <input type="submit" value="Run!">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One issue: HTTP uses `\r\n` for line endings in the header, you're using `\n`.

Comment: but im coding in c which uses \n ?